# ruby on rails: heroku: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, environment-variables

I added the key into heroku config var, but I'm still getting the error.

Is this the correct way? I ignored secrets.yml as I read from other sources that its not a good idea to push this to the public.

in the heroku config var:

```
[key] SECRET_KEY_BASE
[value] 3280570382948240938
```

in **secrets.yml**

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

What am I still doing wrong?

Furthermore, if I put my secret keys into heroku's config variable, don't other developers get to see this too? So, isn't that still kind of public? I've always wondered this concept.

Comment: Other developers cannot see your environment variables, since each Heroku app runs on a separate virtual service instance.

Answer (score 10):

you can set environment variable with `heroku config`

first generate secret key with run below command on terminal

```
rake secret
```

Now use that key on below command

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE='put here new generated key'
```

you can refer this link for more refference

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue today, but for me the solution was a bit different. I realized that in my local environment, I had been using:

```
Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

but for Heroku, instead use:

```
Rails.application.secret_key_base
```

^This worked in my local environment as well. Not sure what the extra `.secrets` is for.

Comment: I also had the same issue which this fixed. Rails 6 + following a Scotch Rails API tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

here is a fool-proof way to set the secret key base with heroku:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rake secret)
```

you can see it with `heroku config:get SECRET_KEY_BASE`

and check that rails picks it up with `Rails.application.secret_key_base` (in `heroku run rails console` for instance)