# "No verification key available" when attempting to access API secured by Devise JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-jwt

I have the gem `devise-jwt` installed. I can perform a login request, and receive an Authorization token in return, but when I try to access a secured endpoint, I receive the message: `No verification key available.`

```
blaine@devbox:~/langsite/backend [master] $ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIwZWNjMmIzNi04ZmZiLTQ2Y2QtYTZkNi1iZGRjZmU4YTQxNmMiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoidXNlciIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNjA1ODQ2NjczLCJleHAiOjE2MDU4NzU0NzN9.ZyqvylXeLZbrRM2V2s5qsyHxiGgElng58HwQ8qjOHCU" http://localhost:3001/quiz_sentences.json
{"error":"No verification key available"}
```

This is what I have in my `config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

```
config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_jwt
    jwt.dispatch_requests = [
        ['POST', %r{^/users/sign_in$}],
        ['GET', %r{^/$}]
    ]
    jwt.request_formats = { user: [:json] }
    jwt.expiration_time = 8.hours.to_i
end
```

I can log in just fine and receive an Authorization token:

```
blaine@devbox:~/langsite/backend [master] $ curl -D - -X POST -d "user[email]=brlafreniere@gmail.com&user[password]=blaine" http://localhost:3001/users/sign_in.json
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Location: /
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIwZWNjMmIzNi04ZmZiLTQ2Y2QtYTZkNi1iZGRjZmU4YTQxNmMiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoidXNlciIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNjA1ODQ4MDQ2LCJleHAiOjE2MDU4NzY4NDZ9.66Hg_NG3E79-ybC4rJK_XkkSxpLcWHWTlOiw96hyvjg
ETag: W/"cfe36cdecee4080492f63e8c8f0c091b"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: c961fc61-a1b4-49f0-bc16-63f19a0abd22
X-Runtime: 0.279213
Vary: Origin
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It seems that I have the Authorization header exposed as well:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource('*',
            headers: :any,
            expose: ["Authorization"],
            methods: :any
        )
    end
end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
    :rememberable, :validatable, :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: self
end
```

I'm pretty much baffled, any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is happening to me as well! Only on my remote server. Locally it works fine. Additionally, if i start the server without daemonizing it, it works fine! I'm still digging into it, but as a work around, I ended up SSH-ing into the instance and starting Puma manually

Comment: Thank you so much for this question !!! Saved me after many hours digging for a solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TLDR; Confirm `jwt.secret` is actually being set**

I had this same issue, in my case it was caused because the `jwt.secret` was not being read correctly, when starting Puma via `systemd`.

```rb
config.jwt do |jwt|
 jwt.secret = ENV['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] # was blank, only if starting via systemd or other daemon
 jwt.dispatch_requests = [
   ['POST', %r{^/login$}]
 ]
 jwt.revocation_requests = [
   ['DELETE', %r{^/logout$}]
 ]
 jwt.expiration_time = 2.weeks.to_i
end
```

---

For some reason, on the remote server, when launching via `systemd` service, `env['JWT_SECRET_KEY']` was empty. However, when starting Puma manually, it worked fine.

I found this out, by hard coding a string as the secret. Suddenly it worked.

```rb
config.jwt do |jwt|
 jwt.secret = "012345678901234567890123456789" # Suddenly worked
 jwt.dispatch_requests = [
   ['POST', %r{^/login$}]
 ]
 jwt.revocation_requests = [
   ['DELETE', %r{^/logout$}]
 ]
 jwt.expiration_time = 2.weeks.to_i
end
```

If `jwt.secret` is empty, it will still generate an `auth token` for whatever reason. Like you this threw me off, as it made me assume my setup was correct.

---

To test if you're running into a similar issue, temporarily hardcode gibberish as the secret. If that works, then you're on the right track

Obviously you should not hard code the string, but rather look into and confirm that your secret is being fed correctly into the above config.

For me that meant specifying an `EnvironmentFile` in the `systemd` service configuration which contains `key=value` pairs (much like a `dotenv` file).

Comment: Thank you so much this saved hours of anguish.

Comment: oh my god, I had my environment variable commented out in my .env file... thank you for the solution

Comment: That was not my specific problem, but I noticed (after many hours) I forgot to add JWT_SECRET_KEY at k8s files.

Answer (score 1):

This question matched my issue but led me to a different answer per this question: [ruby on rails: heroku: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167835/ruby-on-rails-heroku-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment)

For others getting this issue - Check to see if you are using Rails.application.secret_key_base (and not Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by using warden-jwt_auth. 0.7.0 broke, but downgrading to 0.6.0 works. if anyone comes across this :) might help

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are working with containers, pass the environment variables in the `docker-compose` or when you are building the container. If you just write it in the `.env` file, it won't be read by the program