# "No verification key available" when attempting to get User from API secured by JWT Gem

Tags: heroku, jwt, ruby-on-rails-6

I have added the jwt gem to gem file. I can successfully perform a login request, and receive an Authorisation token.
I then use the authorisation token to return the User Object.
This works fine in development.

However, in production, I am unable to get the User Object using the authorisation token.
I receive the message: No verification key available.

My searches led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923974/no-verification-key-available-when-attempting-to-access-api-secured-by-devise) but this is for devise-jwt
I also came across [this](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt/decode.rb) but it wasn't so helpful.

The information from `heroku logs --tail --app stag` isn't really helpful

```
2020-11-25T20:15:30.493583+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-25T20:15:30.493522 #4]  INFO -- : [398a1a9c-fae2-454a-b991-5a922a679103] [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.07ms)
2020-11-25T20:15:30.493805+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-25T20:15:30.493736 #4]  INFO -- : [398a1a9c-fae2-454a-b991-5h922a679973] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (Views: 0.5ms | Allocations: 1356)
```

Any help on this will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, I was struggling with this for the whole day, hope someone will give us some clue about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for my case. I don't know if it's going to work for you, here is what I did:

First I was using `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` as a secret key for my JWT and after reading a bit from other posts with the same issue but using `devise-jwt` I said maybe this attribute in Rails secrets is returning nil in Heroku, so I decided to create my own secret key, and that what I did exactly, I just used an environment variable called secret_key then reference it, where I should use it in JWT.

hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution back then.
I forgot to answer my question.