# Rails API 422 Unprocessable Entity: No verification key available, heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, jwt, authorization

I created a Rails API with a JWT authentication system and deployed it to Heroku. When I request the endpoints locally, all seems to be working fine but when I make requests to the live endpoints (i.e the Heroku deployed app) I get a: `422 Unprocessable Entity` server error and the response body looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "No verification key available"
}
```

The class responsible for encoding and decoding the auth token is defined as follows:

```
class JsonWebToken
  # secret to encode and decode token
  HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base

  def self.encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
    # set expiry to 24 hours from the creation time.
    payload[:exp] = exp.to_i

    # sign token with application secret
    JWT.encode(payload, HMAC_SECRET)
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    # get payload, first index in decoded Array
    body = JWT.decode(token, HMAC_SECRET)[0]
    HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
    # rescue from all decode errors
  rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
    # raise custom error to be handled by custom handler
    raise ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken, e.message
  end
end
```

I have an endpoint `/signup` where I can make a POST request to register a new user and `POST /todos` which is accessible and available only to registered users. Making a registration request works perfectly fine, but when I try to make the POST request to the `/todos` endpoint it raises an error.

The association between user and suit is 1:m respectively.

Please if you have any idea on how I can fix this, I'll be very grateful, thanks : ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured a way out by altering the `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` to `Rails.application.secret_key_base`. For a more detailed review on this please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923974/no-verification-key-available-when-attempting-to-access-api-secured-by-devise). Hopefully, this will help someone facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was also my problem. After checking out my `json_web_token.rb` file, **I figured out that I had written the following line:**

```rb
HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

**There is an extra `secrets` reference, which is causing the problem**. It should be:

```rb
HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secret_key_base
```

But as far as I'm concerned, you managed to figure it out yourself!